# Integrate seems to give wrong results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Below are the two codes that i tried:

Code1:

```
Clear[R, r, \[Theta]];
$Assumptions = True;
$Assumptions = {R, r, \[Theta]} \[Element] Reals && R > 0 && r > 0;
Integrate[(Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/((1 + r^2*R^2*Cos[   [Theta]]^2)^2 + 4 r^2*R^4*Cos[\[Theta]]^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^2), {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Assumptions -> R > 0 && r > 0]
```

I get following output in Mathematica 10.0:

```
(\[Pi] (2 r + r^3 R^2 + 
4 Sqrt[1 + r^2 (R^2 + R^4)]))/(2 r R^2 Sqrt[(1 + 
r^2 (R^2 + R^4)) (4 + r^2 (1 + 4 R^2) + r^4 (R^2 + 2 R^4) + 
4 r Sqrt[1 + r^2 (R^2 + R^4)] + 
2 r^3 R^2 Sqrt[1 + r^2 (R^2 + R^4)])])
```

Code2:

```
Clear[R, r, \[Theta]];
$Assumptions = True;
$Assumptions = {R, r, \[Theta]} \[Element] Reals && R > 0 && r > 0;
R=1;
Integrate[(Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/((1 + r^2*R^2*Cos[   [Theta]]^2)^2 + 4 r^2*R^4*Cos[\[Theta]]^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^2), {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Assumptions -> R > 0 && r > 0]
```

This has following output:

```
-1/(2 r Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2] Abs[-4 - 3 r^2 + r^4])
I (\[Pi] (2 r + r^3 + 4 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]) Sqrt[-4 - 5 r^2 - 3 r^4 + 
   4 r Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2] + 
   2 r^3 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]] + (2 r + r^3 - 4 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]) Sqrt[
  4 + 5 r^2 + 3 r^4 + 4 r Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2] + 2 r^3 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]]
   Log[(3 r - 2 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2])/
   Sqrt[-4 - 5 r^2 - 3 r^4 + 4 r Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2] + 
    2 r^3 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]]] + (-2 r - r^3 + 
    4 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]) Sqrt[
  4 + 5 r^2 + 3 r^4 + 4 r Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2] + 2 r^3 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]]
   Log[(-3 r + 2 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2])/
   Sqrt[-4 - 5 r^2 - 3 r^4 + 4 r Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2] + 
    2 r^3 Sqrt[1 + 2 r^2]]])
```

Since code2 is a special case of code1, there is something wrong with one of them and i am unable to figure that out. It would be extremely helpful if someone could tell me what's wrong with the code/Mathematica?

Comment: 1) How long does it take to get your results? I let mine run for a few minutes without getting anything out. 2) You probably shouldn't set `$Assumptions` and also use the `Assumptions ->` option in `Integrate`. That seems redundant and may lead to subtle inconsistencies.

Comment: I agree, I'll remove $Assumptions option. It takes 1-2 minute on my system..